# How can I fix insecure loaded images on wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a https page and I get an error message in my console for all featured images of my blog entries:

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://www.mypage.com/wp-content/images/myimage.jpg” on a secure page
```

Where exaclty can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to serve the images from a secure URL (https vs http), and you'll also have to configure the image resources to point to the secure URL. 
If you have an image that is http://myblog.com/wp-content/images/myimage.jpg, you can try to go to your WordPress General Settings and change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) from HTTP to HTTPS.

Here's a page with a number of ways to fix the issue
https://wpwarfare.com/resolving-mixed-content-warnings-wordpress-ssl-settings/